# Dominant separated morphism between reduced schemes induces injective stalk homomorphism ? ( Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, Lemma 15.19 )

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am reading the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, proof of Lemma 15.19 ( or Lemma 14.18 in the second edition ) and stuck at some statement. I've searched for math stack exchnage, but there doesn't seem to be any related questions, so I'm asking this.

**Q.1** Let $X$ be a reduced scheme with finitely many irreducible components, $Y$ is a reduced scheme and let $f:X\to Y$ be a dominant separated morphism. Then for all $x\in X$, the induced stalk homomorphism $ f_x^{\sharp} : \mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)} \to \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is injective?

To attempt prove this question, I propose relavant question.

**Q.2** Let $\varphi : A\to B$ be an injective ring homomorphism between reduced rings and $\mathfrak{p}\subseteq B$ a prime ideal. Then the induced homomorphism $\overline{\varphi} : A_{\varphi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})} \to B_{\mathfrak{p}} , a/s \mapsto \varphi(a)/\varphi(s) $ (?) is also injective?

My first strategy for the first question is as follows. Fix $x\in X$. Choose an affine neighborhood $f(x) \in \operatorname{Spec}A=:V \subseteq Y$. Since the separatedness is local on target, $f^{-1}(V) \to V$ is also separated. Since the affine scheme $V:=\operatorname{Spec}A$ is separated and the composition of separated morphisms is also separated, we note that $f^{-1}(V)$ is separated scheme. So by https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01ZX ( $\because$ the nunmber of irreduiclbe components of $f^{-1}(V)$ is finite since the irreducible components of $f^{-1}(V)$ are precisely the intersections between $f^{-1}(V)$ and the irreducible components of $X$ which are nonempty), there exists a dense affine open subset $x \in U:=\operatorname{Spec}B \subseteq f^{-1}(V)$. Note that since $f$ is dominant, $$\overline{f(U)}^{V} = \overline{f(\overline{U})}^V= \overline{f(f^{-1}(V))}^V =\overline{(f(X) \cap V)}^V=\overline{f(X)}^Y \cap V = Y\cap V =V.$$

So $f|_U^V : U:=\operatorname{Spec}B \to V:=\operatorname{Spec}A$ is also dominant (between affine schemes). So the kernel of $\varphi:=\Gamma(f|_U^{V}) : A\to B$ consists of nilpotent elements ( $\because$ Gortz's book Corollary 2.11 ). Since $A$ is reduced ring ($\because$ $Y$ is a reduced scheme ), $\varphi$ is injective.

So, if our second question is true, then $f^{\sharp}_x = \overline{\varphi} : A_{\varphi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p}_x)} \to B_{\mathfrak{p}_x} $ is injective. And is it really true? Or is there any other (simpler) route to show the injectivity of $f^{\sharp}_x$?

**EDIT :** My first attempt for the question 2 above is as follows.

Let $\overline{\varphi}(a/s) = \varphi(a)/\varphi(s) = 0/1 $ in $B_{\mathfrak{p}}$. Then there exists $l\in B- \mathfrak{p}$ such that $l \varphi(a)=0$. From this, can we show that $a/s = 0/1 $ in $A_{\varphi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})}$  ; i.e., there exists $s' \in A- \varphi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$ such that $s'a=0$ ? If we can show that "there exists $s' \in A-\varphi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$ such that $l=\varphi(s')$", then $l \varphi(a)= \varphi(s'a)=0$, and since $\varphi$ is injective, $s'a=0$ and we are done. But is it true? How can we make progress? Can we use the reducedness of $A$ and $B$ ? If so, how?

This question originates from following proof of the Lemma 14.18 in the Gortz's book :

> Lemma 15.19.( or Lemma 14.18 in the second edition ) Let $X$ be a scheme with finitely many irreducible components and let $f:X\to Y$ be a separated morphism. If there exists a covering $X= \cup_{i\in I}U_i$ by dense open subsets $U_i \subseteq X$ such that for all $i$, $f|_{U_i}$ is an immersion (resp. an open immersion), then $f$ is an immersion (resp. an open immersion).

*Proof.* It suffices to show that $f$ is injecitve. We may assume that $X$ and $Y$ are reduced. Replacing $Y$ by $\overline{f(X)}$, endowed with its reduced scheme structure, we may assume that $f$ is dominant. As $f$ is locally on $X$ an immersion, $f^{\sharp}_x : \mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)}\to \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is surjective for all $x\in X$ **and hence bijective because $f$ is dominant and $X$, $Y$ are reduced.** Thus $f$ is flat and therefore two projections $\operatorname{pr}_i : X \times_Y X \to X$ ($i=1,2$) are flat. Thus $\operatorname{pr}_i(X\times_Y X)$ is stable under generization in $X$ ( Lemma 14.9 ). ( Next proof is omitted.. )

Why the bold statement is true?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Yes, Q.2 is true. Imo it is an easy exercise in commutative algebra. What did you try to solve it?

Comment: @red_trumpet : O.K. I upload my attempt for the Q.2. in the EDIT. Can you see? How can I proceed?  How can we use the reducedness?

Comment: I see, I had integral domains in mind.

Comment: @red_trumpet : O.K. I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain the proof of Görtz-Wedhorn, start with the following lemma.

**Lemma.** If $Y$ is a reduced scheme and $f: X \to Y$ is a dominant immersion, then $f$ is an open immersion.

*Proof*. We may factor $f$ as a closed immersion $i: X \to V$, followed by an open immersion $j: V \to Y$. Since $j$ is an open immersion, $V$ is reduced. Also, as $f$ is dominant, and $i$ is closed, $j$ is an open immersion, $i(X) = V$.

P.s. Indeed we can show that $i$ is dominant ; i.e., $\overline{i(X)}=V$ so that $i(X)=V$ since $i$ is closed. **Sketch of proof** : Assume that $\overline{i(X)} \neq V$. Then there exists $l \in V-\overline{i(X)}$. So $l$ is not point of closure of $i(X)$ so that there exists an open $W\subseteq V$ with $l\in W$ but $W\cap i(X) = \varnothing$. Now let $y:=j(l)$. Then we can show that $y\in Y-\overline{f(X)}$, which is contradiction to dominance of $f$, as follows. By contrary, assume $y\in \overline{f(X)}$ so that $y$ is point of closure of $f(X)$. So for any open set $U\subseteq Y$ with $y\in U$, $f(X)\cap U \neq \varnothing$. But $U:=j(W)$, which is open subset of $Y$ since $j$ is open immersion, does not satisfy such condition (here we use that $f= j\circ i$ and the injectivity of $j$  ), which is contradiction.

As $V$ is reduced, this implies that $i$ is an isomorphism (think locally: for an ideal $I \subset A$, you have $V(I) = \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ if and only if $I \subset \bigcap_{\mathfrak p} \mathfrak p = \sqrt{0}$). Hence $f = j \circ i$ is an open immersion.

Now Görtz and Wedhorn assume that for each $x \in X$ there is a dense open neighborhood $U \subset X$, such that $f|_U: U \to Y$ is an immersion. Since $\overline{U} = X$, $\overline{f(U)} = \overline{f(\overline{U})} = \overline{f(X)} = Y$. By an application of the lemma above, $f|_U: U \to Y$ is an open immersion. Hence it induces isomorphisms on stalks,
$$f_x^\#: \mathcal O_{Y,f(x)} \xrightarrow{\cong} \mathcal O_{X,x}.$$

To be honest, I find the argument given by Görtz and Wedhorn a bit misleading. Indeed, your **Q.2** is wrong. Here is a counterexample:

Take $X = \mathbb A^1 \sqcup \mathbb A^1 = \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb C[x] \times \mathbb C[y])$, and $Y = \{\, xy = 0 \,\} \subset
\mathbb A^2$. The map $f$ sends one copy of $\mathbb A^1$ isomorphically to
$\{\, x = 0\,\} \subset Y$, and the other one to $\{\, y = 0\,\}$.
Algebraically this means $$\varphi: \mathbb C[x,y] / (xy) \hookrightarrow \mathbb C[x] \times \mathbb C[y], \quad g \mapsto (g \mod y, g \mod x).$$
But if we localize on the right hand side with respect to the prime ideal $\mathfrak p_0 = \{0\} \times \mathbb C[y]$, then you see that $\varphi$ becomes $g \mapsto g \mod y$, which has a kernel. Localizing further will not get rid of this kernel.

Geometrically this happens because the components which contain a point $p \in X$ do *not* dominate the components of $Y$ which contain $f(p)$.

---

Here is a variant of **Q.2** which works:

**Proposition.** If $Y$ is a reduced scheme, $f: X \to Y$ a morphism of scheme, and the components which contain $x \in X$ dominate the components which contain $f(x)$, then $f_x^\#: \mathcal O_{Y,f(x)} \to \mathcal O_{X,x}$ is injective.

*Proof*. You basically proved the case where $Y$ is irreducible, because then you may assume that the ring $A$ is an integral domain, so that $l \varphi(a) = 0$ implies $\varphi(a) = 0$ (since $l \neq 0$).

For the general case, write $\mathfrak q = \varphi^{-1}(\mathfrak p)$.
Pick an irreducible component $Y_0 \subset Y$, which corresponds to $A
\twoheadrightarrow A_0$. The kernel of this map is a minimal prime ideal of $A$, contained in $\mathfrak q$. By assumption there exists an irreducible component
$X_0 \subset X$, containing $x$, which dominates $Y_0$. This corresponds to $B
\twoheadrightarrow B_0$. By the case for irreducible $Y$, the morphism $$(A_0)_{\mathfrak q} \to (B_0)_{\mathfrak p}$$
is injective.
From the commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A_{\mathfrak q} @>>> B_{\mathfrak p}\\
@VVV @VVV \\
(A_0)_{\mathfrak q} @>>> (B_0)_{\mathfrak p}
\end{CD}$$
we see that $\operatorname{Ker}(A_{\mathfrak
q} \to B_{\mathfrak p})$ is contained in
$$\operatorname{Ker}(A_{\mathfrak q} \to (A_0)_{\mathfrak q} \to  (B_0)_{\mathfrak p}) = \operatorname{Ker}(A_{\mathfrak q} \to (A_0)_{\mathfrak q}).$$
The equality here holds by the injectivity of the second map.
Now as $Y_0$ runs through all irreducible components containing $f(x)=\mathfrak q$, $\operatorname{Ker}(A_{\mathfrak q} \to (A_0)_{\mathfrak q})$ runs through all mininmal prime ideals of $A_{\mathfrak q}$ ($\because$ [For an affine open subscheme $\operatorname{Spec}A$, $\{ \operatorname{ker}(A_q \to (A_0)_q )\} = \{ \operatorname{minimal prime ideals of} A_q \}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4879408/for-an-affine-open-subscheme-operatornamespeca-operatornamekera-q/4880021#4880021.)) But the intersecion of all minimal prime ideals is the nilradical $\sqrt{0}$, and $\sqrt{0}= 0$, as $Y$ is assumed to be reduced.

---

I wrote the authors, and Görtz agreed with me. [Here is the relevant erratum](https://www.algebraic-geometry.de/errata/2/#e864)

Comment: Thanks, Brilliant. O.K. Let me follow your argument. We have a dominant morphism $f|_U^V : U:=\operatorname{Spec}B \to V:=\operatorname{Spec}A$. Let $x\in X_0$  be an irreducible component containing $x$. Then $X_0 \cap U = V(I)=\operatorname{Spec}(B_0:=B/I)$ is a closed subscheme of $U$. Since $f|_{X_0 \cap U}^{V} : X_0 \cap U \to V$ is dominant, $\overline{\varphi_1} := \Gamma(f|_{X_0 \cap U}^{V}) : A \to B_0$ is injective. If $B_0$ is integral, then $A_\mathfrak{q} \to (B_0)_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is injective.

Comment: And from letting $\iota: X_0 \cap U \hookrightarrow U$, by taking $\Gamma$ to $f|_{U}^V \circ \iota$, we have $A\to B \to B/I$. And so on.. Am I following well?

Comment: Q.1.) How can we gaurantee that $B_0$ is integral domain? $X_0 \cap U$ is irreducible. But how can we show that $B_0$ is reduced ring? Although $B$ is reduced ring, its quotient $B_0 = B/I$ may not be reduced?                                                                  
Q.2.) If I am following well your argument, why $f|_{X_0 \cap U}^{V} : X_0 \cap U \to V$ is dominant? If $X_0 \cap U$ is dense in $U$, we can show that, but if not..

Comment: @Plantation If $B_0$ is not reduced, mod out its nilradical to make it reduced. Put differently, we endow $X_0$ with its reduced induced subscheme structure. You are right that $X_0 \to Y$ need not be dominant, this only works of $Y$ is irreducible (see my counterexample). I will write something for how to salvage Gortz-Wedhorns argument.

Comment: O.K. Let's keep going !

Comment: @Plantation I think I got a full solution now. Thanks for watching me work through this :D

Comment: You're welcome! Btw, your speed of argument is so fast for me  :) Q.1.) Why $\operatorname{Ker}(A_{\mathfrak{q}}\to  (A_0)_{\mathfrak{q}})$ runs through all minimal prime ideals of of $A_{\mathfrak{q}}$? Q.2.) Why that $f$ is locally immersion implies the dominant condition in the proposition? :) Perhaps, Can you teach me about this stuff more in detail? Please understand my speed of understanding ~

Comment: I understand your overall strategy. And.. in the proof, we have an irreducible component $x\in X_0 \subseteq X$ which dominates $f(x) \in Y_0 \subseteq Y$.  If $X_0 \cap U= \operatorname{Spec}(B_0)$ ( endowed with the reduced subscheme structure ) also dominates $Y_0 \cap V= \operatorname{Spec}(A_0)$, then we can obtain injective map $(A_0)_{\mathfrak{q}} \to (B_0)_{\mathfrak{p}}$. And can we really guarantee that $X_0 \cap U$ also dominates $Y_0 \cap V$ along $f$? How?

Comment: In my opinion, I think that for the argument it needs small correction or added explanation to make it more rigorously. Anyway thank you.

Comment: @Plantation You are right, it is not clear why the assumptions of my proposition hold in the case that Görtz and Wedhorn need. Regarding minimal primes, note that $\operatorname{Spec}(A_{\mathfrak q}) \subset \operatorname{Spec}(A)$, and the minimal primes of $A_{\mathfrak q}$ correspond exactly to the irreducible components of $Y$ which contain $f(x)$.

Comment: O.K. And after some testing, as I comment above, I think that the implication of the dominance of $X_0 \cap U$ over $Y_0 \cap V$ along $f$ from the dominance of $X_0$ over $Y_0$ seems like it might not work. There seems to be some delicated issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151986/discussion-between-red-trumpet-and-plantation).