# For an affine open subscheme $\operatorname{Spec}A$, $\{ \operatorname{ker}(A_q \to (A_0)_q )\} = \{ \operatorname{minimal prime ideals of} A_q \}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $V:=\operatorname{Spec}A$ be an affine open subscheme of a scheme $Y$ with $x=\mathfrak{q}_x\in V$. Consider next set

$$\{ Y_0 \cap V : Y_0 \operatorname{is an irreducible component of} Y \operatorname{containing} x=\mathfrak{q}  \} .$$

**Then it is the set of irreducible components of $V:=\operatorname{Spec}A$ containing $x$.** Furthurmore we can endow the reduced subscheme structure on each closed subset $Y_0 \cap V = \operatorname{Spec}(A_0 := A/J_0)$ of $V$. We know that the set of irreducible components of $V$ containing $x$ is in bijective correspondence with the set of minimal priem ideals of $\mathcal{O}_{V,x} = A_{\mathfrak{q}}$ ( $\because$ Theorem 3.33 in [https://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/~conrad/216APage/handouts/irreddim.pdf](https://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/216APage/handouts/irreddim.pdf) )

My question is, then, furthermore, $$\{ \operatorname{ker}(A_{\mathfrak{q}} \to (A_0)_{\mathfrak{q}}) : Y_0 \operatorname{is an irreducible component of} Y \operatorname{containing} x=\mathfrak{q}_x\} = \{ \operatorname{minimal prime ideals of} A_{\mathfrak{q}} \}$$ ?

This question originates from following answer of red_trumpet : [Dominant separated morphism between reduced schemes induces injective stalk homomorphism ? ( Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, Lemma 15.19 )](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4878809/dominant-separated-morphism-between-reduced-schemes-induces-injective-stalk-homo/4878871?noredirect=1#comment10404768_4878871)

If needed, I will upload detailed argument of each proof in the linked question.

In the proposition of the answer of red_trumpet , he mentioned that "Now as $Y_0$ runs through all irreducible components containing $f(x)=\mathfrak q$, $\operatorname{Ker}(A_{\mathfrak q} \to (A_0)_{\mathfrak q})$ runs through all mininmal prime ideals of $A_{\mathfrak q}$." I am trying to understand his sentence and formulate its key issue as a question.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O.K. I think that I solved the problem. I leave an answer as a record.

For simplicity, let $X:=\operatorname{Spec}A$ be an affine scheme with $x:=\mathfrak{p} \in X$. By the hungerford, Algebra, p.147, Theorem 4.11-(i), there exists a bijection :
$$\psi : \{ \operatorname{prime ideals} Q\subseteq A \operatorname{which are contained in} \mathfrak{p}\}  \to \{\operatorname{prime ideals of} A_{\mathfrak{p}} \}$$
$$ Q \mapsto Q_{\mathfrak{p}}$$

And via this bijection, the minimal prime ideals corresponds to the minimal prime ideals so we also obtain bijection :

$$\psi : \{ \operatorname{ minimal prime ideals} Q\subseteq A \operatorname{which are contained in} \mathfrak{p}\}  \to \{\operatorname{minimal prime ideals of} A_{\mathfrak{p}} \}$$
$$ Q \mapsto Q_{\mathfrak{p}} $$

(True?) So, $$\{\operatorname{minimal prime ideals of} A_{\mathfrak{p}} \} = \{ Q_{\mathfrak{p}} : Q \operatorname{is minimal prime ideal of } A \operatorname{such that} Q \subseteq \mathfrak{p}\} \tag{1}.$$

Consider an irreducible component $V(Q)= \operatorname{Spec}(A/Q) \subseteq X:=\operatorname{Spec}A$ containing $\mathfrak{p}$. Then we have natural map $\pi_Q : A\to A_0 := A/Q$ and also get the induced map $A_{\mathfrak{p}} \to (A/Q)_{\mathfrak{p}/Q}$. Then, note that, to show our purpose in question, we need to show that

$$\{\operatorname{ker}(A_{\mathfrak{p}} \to (A/Q)_{\mathfrak{p}/Q}) : V(Q) \operatorname{is irreducible component such that} \mathfrak{p} \in V(Q) \} = \{\operatorname{minimal prime ideals of} A_{\mathfrak{p}} \}.$$

But this is true since $Q_\mathfrak{p} = \operatorname{ker}(A_{\mathfrak{p}} \to (A/Q)_{\mathfrak{p}/Q})$ by straightforward proof and

$$\{\operatorname{ker}(A_{\mathfrak{p}} \to (A/Q)_{\mathfrak{p}/Q}) : V(Q) \operatorname{is irreducible component such that} \mathfrak{p} \in V(Q) \} = \{\operatorname{ker}(A_{\mathfrak{p}} \to (A/Q)_{\mathfrak{p}/Q}) : Q \operatorname{is minimal prime ideal of} A \operatorname{such that} Q \subseteq \mathfrak{p}\} = \{Q_{\mathfrak{p}} : Q \operatorname{is minimal prime ideal of} A \operatorname{such that} Q \subseteq \mathfrak{p}\}. $$

(For the second equality, we used the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry Corollary 2.7. : The map $\mathfrak{p} \mapsto V(\mathfrak{p})= \overline{\{ \mathfrak{p}\}}$ is a bijection from $\operatorname{Spec}A$ onto the set of closed irreducible subsets of $\operatorname{Spec}A$. Via this bijection, the minimal prime ideals of $A$ correspond to the irreducible components of $\operatorname{Spec}A$. )

Then by the above $(1)$, we are done.